# Rails: no such file to load -- openssl when generate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm

I am using **Rails 3.1.1** and **ruby 1.9.2-p290**.

When I try to generate model with command:

```
rails generate model Car name:string
```

I got the error message:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
```

I tried to get rid of it by using [method](http://www.isnull.com.ar/2010/11/ruby-rails-this-error-occurred-while.html)

and also tried :

```
cd to ~.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

But, neither of them help. Anyone has any ideas about this error?

Comment: I finally get rid of this problem by :

    apt-get install openssl
    apt-get install libopenssl-ruby

on my ubuntu machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is seems you are missing libraries for openssl.
Try installing these packages.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby1.9.1
```

if you are using rvm then and getting same error then try following

```
rvm pkg install openssl (old code for rvm - rvm package install openssl)
rvm pkg install iconv (old code for rvm - rvm package install iconv)
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr,--with-iconv-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```